# Facebook notification FQL query problems

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to retrieve the current user's notifications from the past 8 hours. I'm using the Graph API Explorer on FQL mode before I put this into my app. On permissions, I have `user_about_me` and `manage_notifications`. The request i'm searching for is this:

```
SELECT notification_id FROM notification WHERE recipient_id={0}
```

But it returns:

```
{
  "error": "Request failed"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error `Request failed`
generally occurs when the your request in not correct.

1. If you read the documentation properly, this API is used to fetch -

   > The current user's notifications

   So, only valid `recipient_id` could be the current user's id or `me()`; not his friends or any other user.
2. If you have tried the current user's id to the `recipient_id`, that means the id you've provided with `{0}` is not correct (some syntactical error).

   So, instead you could simply write `recipient_id = me()`